# is there a library to simplify this calculation? or other simple way

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python, specially about data.

Ask permission to ask this question.

i'm try to learn to calculate column with another column. Like the following example:

The Data Frame:

```
ID     Name  Course1  Course2  Course3  Score_course1  Score_Course2  Score_Course3
1       A      4        3.75      3           2              3              3
2       B      2.75      4        4           2              3              3
```

The code i use:

```
df['total'] = ((df['Course1'] * df['Score_Course1']) + (df['Course2'] * df['Score_Course2']) + (df['Course3'] * df['Score_Course3']))
```

but this code is too long. Can I use "for"?.

Or any other suggestions?

Comment: How is that too long?

Comment: There are actually 20 index columns. 10 Course and 10 Score_course

Comment: `df['total'] = sum(df[f'Course{i}'] * df[f'Score_Course{i}'] for i in range(1, 4))` !?

Comment: @machinelearningnewbie Why didn't you say that to begin with? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
   ID Name  Course1  Course2  Course3  Score_Course1  Score_Course2  Score_Course3
0   1    A     4.00     3.75        3              2              3              3
1   2    B     2.75     4.00        4              2              3              3
```

Doing:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['ID', 'Name'], stubnames=['Course', 'Score_Course'], j='Course_Num').reset_index()
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   ID Name  Course_Num  Course  Score_Course
0   1    A           1    4.00             2
1   1    A           2    3.75             3
2   1    A           3    3.00             3
3   2    B           1    2.75             2
4   2    B           2    4.00             3
5   2    B           3    4.00             3
```

Now we can do the desired calculation easily:

```
# In one go:
df2.groupby(['ID', 'Name']).apply(lambda x: sum(x.Course * x.Score_Course)).reset_index(name='scores')

# OR

# In two steps:
df2['scores'] = df2.Course.mul(df2.Score_Course)
df2.groupby(['ID', 'Name'], as_index=False)[['scores']].sum()
```

Output:

```
   ID Name  scores
0   1    A   28.25
1   2    B   29.50
```

`df2` after two-steps version:

```
   ID Name  Course_Num  Course  Score_Course  scores
0   1    A           1    4.00             2    8.00
1   1    A           2    3.75             3   11.25
2   1    A           3    3.00             3    9.00
3   2    B           1    2.75             2    5.50
4   2    B           2    4.00             3   12.00
5   2    B           3    4.00             3   12.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the example you provided is a truncated version and you have many other couples [course-score], or even a non constant number of couples. Am I right?
If so, I think the best approach woudld be to pivot your Dataframe to a tidyer format like this:

| ID | Name | Course_number | Course_value | Course_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 4 | 3.75 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 2.75 | 4 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 3 | 3 | 3 |

See [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function to reshape your Dataframe like this.

With this new shape you can then:

1. Store the the product of `Course_value * Course_score` into a dedicated column (ie: "product"). See [pandas.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
2. Group by Name. See [pandas.grouby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
3. Summarise your groups by calculating the group-wise sum of the product column

It will produce a Dataframe like this:

| ID | Name | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 24.3 |
| 2 | B | 28 |